# "I don't mind paying/watching/going"

Tags: grammar, syntax

I've seen a lot of posts with conditionals "if you don't mind... then" and such. But I was wondering how you would make a sentence with 'mind + gerundio'. I've seen the verb 'かまう' and 'きにする' but I wouldn't know how to structure the sentence. For example:

> 'I don't mind paying' (when someone offers you a service for free)
>
> 'I don't mind watching this film' (when some suggests a film that is unpopular with the groups decision'

I'll try anyway:

> はらってかまわないよ。
> この映画をみてきにしない。

Or if this structure is too literal in Japanese, I'd appreciate an alternate structure.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to explain logically, but the form of …して かまわない is practically used when you let other people do something, rather than yourself. When you include yourself, you use …しても いい (recommended) or …するのは かまわない.

この映画をみて きにしない means "I watch this film, nevertheless, I don't care", and doesn't work for your intended meaning. Incidentally, …みるのは きにしない means "I don't care (other people) watching it".